# Serie of functions : interchange of limit of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that if $f_n$ is continuous for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$, then for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lim_{t \rightarrow x}f_n(t)$$

Could anyone give any suggestion how to prove this statement ?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint: The uniform convergence of a sequence of continuous functions converges to a continuous function.*

Let $s_k(t)=\sum_{1}^{k}f_{n}(t)$ be the partial sum of the series. Clearly $s_k(t)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ for all $k$. Then $$f(t):=\sum_{1}^{\infty}f_{n}(t)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}s_k (t)$$ is continuous by *Hint*, that is, $\lim_{t\rightarrow x}f(t)=f(x)$. So $$\lim_{t\rightarrow x}\sum_{1}^{\infty}f_{n}(t)=\sum_{1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)\Longrightarrow \lim_{t\rightarrow x}\sum_{1}^{\infty}f_{n}(t)=\sum_{1}^{\infty}\lim_{t\rightarrow x}f_{n}(t)$$ since each $f_n$ is itself continuous.