# Be: $\phi(t)=\frac{1}{t}\left(e^{t A}-I\right)$ Find: $\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \phi(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Be $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, and the matricial function $\phi:(0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$:
> $$\phi(t)=\frac{1}{t}\left(e^{t A}-I\right)$$
> Find: $\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \phi(t)$.

First of all I know that $\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \phi(t) = A$, So:

Here I demostrated that:
$$ e^{t A}-I-A t=\sum_{j=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j !}(t A)^{j}$$
Then, be
$  \delta \in(0,1)$
$\rightarrow0<t<\delta$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|\phi(t)-A\| &=\frac{1}{t}\left\|e^{t A}-I-A t\right\| \\
& \leqslant \frac{1}{t} \sum_{j=2}^{\infty} \frac{t^j}{j !}\|A\|^{j}=\frac{1}{t}\left(e^{\|A\|}-I-\|A\|\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
So, I have that: $\|\phi(t)-A\| \leqslant \frac{1}{t}\left(e^{\|A\|}-I-\|A\|\right)$

what can I do after that to complete the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small mistake: your last line should be
$$\frac{1}{t} (e^{t\|A\|} - 1 - t\|A\|).$$
You can use l'Hopital's rule to show the limit is zero as $t \to 0$.

Alternatively, you can go back to the series $\sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{t^{j-1}}{j!} \|A\|^j$ and take $t \to 0$ term by term, and [appeal to uniform convergence of the series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701827/serie-of-functions-interchange-of-limit-of-series).

Comment: Thanks so much, i can solve using your second alternative.